# are document.all and document.layers obsolete now

Tags: javascript

I am going through some (old?) native javascript and I encountered a separation of document.getElementById, document.all and document.layers.

From what I know, document.all and document.layers are obsolete now, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Royi Namir: the latest releases of chrome and opera also support `document.all`

Comment: @Dr.Molle ouch....didn't know that.:-) thanks. (deleting)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, they are obsolete.

The `document.all` collection is specific to Internet Explorer. The `document.layers` collection was specific to Netscape. Neither is in the standards.

Today we use `document.getElementById` instead.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ#JavaScript_doesn.E2.80.99t_work.21_Why.3F

Comment: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp) documentation also supports this. As neither property is listed.

Comment: @fredrik: Thanks for that, but note that w3schools isn't complete enough to be used as documentation. You can use it as a tutorial, as long as you consider that some parts of it may be incorrect or outdated.

Comment: Of course I meant document.getElementById and not document.id. Brainfart from my side...

Comment: @Guffa Of course - no school ever has complete documentation of anything :D

Comment: Off-topic: I've often found information on w3schools unreliable- better not rely or recommend it. :-)  http://w3fools.com/ has more info about it.

Comment: @vsr: Note thought that w3fools lists some issues where w3schools are actually correct.

Comment: @Guffa as today is almost 4 years later don't you think we could update your answer especially the part with `Today we use document.getElementById instead.` and say: Today we use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are. They comes from a period where Internet Explorer 4 and Netscape 4.x were the main browsers: `document.layers` was used by Netscape, and `document.all` from IE. The first is definitely unused anymore, where I guess `document.all` is still used for legacy in IEs.

Answer (score 0):

document.all is supported by most (if not all) modern browsers. It is just considered false if you try to test for it, but will work if you use it (IIRC, they wanted to discourage people from using it to test for IE).

To really test for it you can use try .... catch. What I tested was:

var da = document.all.length;

which throws an error if document.all isn't supported.

The modern equivalent of document.all is document.getElementsByTagName('*')

Comment: "*they wanted to discourage people from using it to test for IE*" - rather, they wanted to stay compatible with code by the people who used it to test for IE, while at the same time supporting code written only for IE.

Comment: It seems you are answering the question "*How test for support of `document.all`?*", not the question asked by the OP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35697922)