# Javascript not reloading page when I switched to Chrome from IE

Tags: javascript

I have been using this code with IE for sometime to reload a page after 5 seconds of no activity. I cant figure out why it stopped working in chrome.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
if (document.layers) {
    window.captureEvent(onmousemove); 
} 
document.onmousemove = oreset
var tID = ''; 
function oreset(){ 
    clearTimeout(tID) 
    count=0 
    reloadPage() 
} 
function reloadPage(){ 
    count++ 
    if(count==5){ // 5 seconds 
        window.location="/sd/clockin/testclockin.php"; 
    } 
    tID = setTimeout("reloadPage()",1000); 
} 
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: try putting this in `setTimeout` as the first argument instead: `function(){reloadPage()}` and drop the quotes

Comment: works fine for me and btw, `document.layers` isn't used anymore

Comment: hmm, it seems to be that Chrome is firing the `mousemove` event constantly, even when the mouse is still. I'll look into it. Even when i turn off my mouse.

Comment: ok, i got a somewhat hacky workaround going. See my answer

Comment: @Ronnie why? My Netscape 4 uses `document.layers` just fine - works really well with all my `<marquee>` tags and gifs. I'm having quite the internet.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum sorry, I shouldn't have said "not used", but they are not standard anymore. Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854504/are-document-all-and-document-layers-obsolete-now

Comment: @CesarBielich, could you see if my answer solves the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why that doesn't work in Chrome, but here's a script that is kind've better overall:

```
var expirer=setTimeout(expireFunc,5000);
function expireFunc(){
    window.location.replace('/sd/clockin/testclockin.php');//or use .href instead if you don't like replace
}
//work around the random chrome bug here
var lastX=0,lastY=0;
window.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    //more workaround stuff
    if(e.clientX===lastX&&e.clientY===lastY)
            return;
    lastX=e.clientX;
    lastY=e.clientY;
    console.log('moved');
    clearTimeout(expirer);
    expirer=setTimeout(expireFunc,5000);
},false);
```

I also had to workaround the bug I explained in the comments. http://jsfiddle.net/7cT9U/ is a working example.