# From Internet Explorer 6 to Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, dom

I am working on an old web application (initially developed for Internet Explorer 6, now upgraded for Internet Explorer 8) and I need to assure compatibility on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. I managed to do it for Mozilla Firefox but it is harder on Google Chrome, menu does not display and I do not know why at all. I have this kind of code (here it is for the main menu and there also is something like that for the submenus which are developed when you hover over menu items):

```
if((document.all)||(window.sidebar)){
        var clic="";
        var style="";
        if(this[i].url!=""){
            style="cursor:pointer;";
            clic=" onclick='window.location=\""+this[i].url+"\"'";}
        A+="<div id='main"+i+"' style='position:absolute; left:"+X+"; top:"+Y+"; "+style+"width:130px"+/*this[i].larg+*/"; height:18px"+/*this.haut+*/"; background-color:"+colBarre+"; "+cssTexte+"; text-align:center' onmouseover='start("+i+", "+this[i].mnu+", "+X+", "+(Y+this.haut+1)+")'"+clic+">"+this[i].txt+"</div>";}
    if(document.layers){
        var txt=this[i].txt;
        if(this[i].url!=""){
            txt="<a href='"+this[i].url+"'>"+txt+"</a>";}
        A+="<layer name='main"+i+"' left="+X+" top="+Y+" width=130px"+/*this[i].larg+*/" height=18px"+/*this.haut+*/" bgcolor="+colBarre+"  onmouseover='start("+i+","+this[i].mnu+", "+X+", "+(Y+this.haut+1)+")'><center><span style='background-color:"+colBarre+cssTexte+"'>"+txt+"</span></center></layer>";}
    X+=this[i].larg+1;}
```

After many researches on the web I still do not understand what document.layers, document.all, window.sidebar, window.getElementById and document.getElementById are, what they return exactly and what the difference between window.getElementById and document.getElementById is.

To sum up: I need information about document.layers, document.all, window.sidebar, window.getElementById and document.getElementById.

Comment: Just plug in Mootools with compatibility layer or jQuery 1.x and let the libraries figure it out. If you don't know yet what `document.all` is you're not going to succeed in doing this yourself anywhere soon.

Comment: I know document.all is from the DOM API but I do not find if it is obsolete or not and if it is obsolete with what I can replace it. I do not find documentation about this so I do not know what document.all returns.

Comment: `all` was never a JavaScript feature, but a Microsoft specific JScript feature; also: “`all` is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use `getElementById`.” See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx As IE8 also knows the `getElementBy…` functions, you should use those

Comment: In general, [refer to Mozilla Development Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document#Properties) as the more readable version of raw W3C specs. As this link shows `document.all` is deprecated (and was indeed as @feeela points out never part of the spec anyway).

Comment: No disrespect, but if you don't know what `document.getElementById` is, it might be best to put this project to rest for a while and start studying the basics of JavaScript.

Comment: `document.layers` is an artifact from Netscape and kind of a 90th nostalgia; [are document.all and document.layers obsolete now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854504/are-document-all-and-document-layers-obsolete-now)

Comment: I mostly want to know what each one returns because they are used in if conditions. And I have already used getElementById that is why I do not understand how it can be used in an if condition without parameter, like here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_Web_Developer_FAQ#JavaScript_doesn.E2.80.99t_work.21_Why.3F

Comment: @capsnew In that example, they are accessing `getElementById` as a variable, not a function, as you can tell by the lack of parentheses (in JavaScript, all functions are variables). If it doesn't exist, it returns `null`, which evaluates to `false`. So it's a feature-check. For any new browser feature, you can check its presence with, eg. `if (window.RobotLibrary)` before calling `window.RobotLibrary.DestroyWorld()`

Comment: @Katana314 Thank you alot for your answer, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved my problem. If someone need an answer, here what I did. document.all and document.layers are both obsolete, already with Internet Explorer 6. So I used document.getElementById instead of document.all and erased all if conditions with document.layer. Last, I did not find what document.all, window.sidebar and document.getElementById return (EDIT: an answer here [From Internet Explorer 6 to Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535109/from-internet-explorer-6-to-google-chrome/31588767#comment51129482_31535109)) but my application works well on IE, MF and GC and that is what I needed so everything is OK.